# Use string with arguments with tools:text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a string with arguments (for example `<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>`). I know, that I can use it at my code with `String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);` and I will get a full message with username and count. But can I preview it in .xml layout, using `tools:text?` or any other `tools` instrument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't.

According to the documentation of [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) and the [Tools-Attribute](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) there is no way to replace the String placeholders in XML.

I was researching this a while ago and ended up hard-coding the text via `tools:text`. As this only affects design previews I think that hardcoding the text is okay in this case.